# Jasmine + AngularJS resourceService is removing `$promise`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I request some resources from the server with `resourceService.newOrGet(...)`. Then I nest the promise resolutions with `then` so that a callback triggers after *all* have been resolved.

This works fine in my browser, but when I run it with karma + jasmine, the `$promise` elements get removed after the first `then`:

```
$scope.a = resourceService.newOrGet('/a.json');
$scope.b = resourceService.newOrGet('/b.json');
$scope.c = resourceService.newOrGet('/c.json');

console.log([!!$scope.a.$promise, !!$scope.b.$promise, !!$scope.c.$promise]);
// => [true, true, true]
$scope.a.$promise.then(() => {
  console.log([!!$scope.a.$promise, !!$scope.b.$promise, !!$scope.c.$promise]);
  // => [true, true, false]
  $scope.b.$promise.then(() => {
    // => [true, true, false]
    $scope.c.$promise.then(() => {
      myCallback();
    }
  }
}
```

In the browser, all of the promises get printed for each `console.log` invocation. But in karma-jasmine, the last `$scope.c.$promise` is `undefined` in all but the first invocation, and I get a

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

error when I reach `$scope.c.$promise.then`.

Any idea why or what I can do about that?

AngularJS v1.5

Comment: did you inject `$scope` into your test suite?

Comment: @starcorn, yes. `$scope` gets injected into the controller in a `beforeEach` hook.